# achartengine x axis labels

Tags: java, android, achartengine, label

I have the following code to draw my bar graph however the x axis labels are not aligning properly. I want the labels to appear over each bar so i aligned them to the right. It appears the achartEngine tries to do this, most of each label appears on the correct side however i still have some text below the x axis.

Help!

```
//Draw graph as desired
mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f1f1f2"));
mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.1);
mRenderer.setYAxisMax(15);
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(70);
mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(30);
//mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(-1000);
mRenderer.setXLabelsAngle(90);
mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {0, 10, -70, 10});

mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.GRAY);
```

[image]

Comment: Any body have any ideas?

Comment: Please post a screenshot.

Comment: Sure, see above... I want the entire label above the x axis

Comment: How does it look when you are using the setXLabelsPadding?

Comment: @Fearghal Have you got resolved the above issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but...

> renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);

Cheers.